# Within Iframe Tracking

Tags: iframe, tracking

I am on a project in which clients ask us to find solution for tracking the user interaction occurring inside an iframe.

*** Scenario:
that is a learning platform.
the way that website works is like this:
once users click on a course, an iframe (A) (embedded in an div) will be loaded, then another iframe (B) containing the content is also loaded inside the iframe A.

*** My task
Figuring out how to track the user interaction inside the iframe B.

*** My current approach is as following:
***** Approach 1:

1. using postMessage to send event from Iframe B to Iframe A
2. then send event from Iframe A to the parent frame
   => it does not work

***** Approach 2:

1. using postMessage also, but now send event from Iframe B to parent frame
   => but only the 'mouseover' is sent, the 'click' or other events are not.

Could someone please give me an advice how to overcome this challenge?

Thanks in advance.

```
var iframeOneHead = document.querySelector('xxxx').contentDocument.querySelector('head');
var iframeTwoHead = document.querySelector('xxx').contentDocument.querySelector('#content').contentDocument.querySelector('head');

/// adding script for event Listner in 2nd iframe

var lastChildIframeScript = document.querySelector('xxx').contentDocument.querySelector('#content').contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
lastChildIframeScript.type ='text/javascript';
lastChildIframeScript.innerHTML = "document.addEventListener('click',function(){var iframeMessage = 'got moused up';window.parent.postMessage(iframeMessage, '*');})"
iframeTwoHead.appendChild(lastChildIframeScript);

/// adding script tag inside iframe
var parenIframeScript = document.querySelector('xxxx').contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
parenIframeScript.type ='text/javascript';
parenIframeScript.innerHTML = "document.addEventListener('message',function(event){var iframeMessage = event.data ;parent.postMessage(iframeMessage, '*');})"
iframeOneHead.appendChild(parenIframeScript);


// adding the event listener for message event in parent frame 
var parentScript = document.createElement('script');
parentScript.type = 'text/javascript';
parentScript.innerHTML= "window.addEventListener('message', function(event){console.log('got moused up');console.log(event);})"
document.body.appendChild(parentScript);
```